# Delete all rows from table in NHibernate

Tags: vb.net, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate

I have an application which use Fluent NHibernate and NHibernate, I have an Generic DAO class,  in this class I have generic methods to persist the data, but I want to create an generic method to delete all records from one table. At this moment I have this method:

```
Public Sub ClearTable(ByVal sTable As String)
    Using session = SessaoNHibernate.OpenSession()
        Using transaction = session.BeginTransaction()
            Try
                session.CreateSQLQuery("delete from " & sTable).ExecuteUpdate()
                transaction.Commit()
                session.Flush()
            Catch ex As Exception
                transaction.Rollback()
            End Try
        End Using
    End Using
End Sub
```

I have a generic class, so I want to create a method that don't need to pass the table name. Because the generic class knows the his type.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just don't run it as an SQL query, and you can pass the class name instead:

```
session.CreateQuery("delete from EntityClass").ExecuteUpdate()
```

Comment: Thanks. I do this: "session.CreateQuery("delete from " & GetType(T).ToString()).ExecuteUpdate()" and it resolve my problem.